# How can I navigate to a page from a dialog window?

Tags: wpf, vb.net

I have a dialog window that I open from a record in a datagrid, this datagrid happens to be inside a Page that is navigated to inside a frame.

I have a button in this window, that when clicked, I would like to navigate the main window (which happens to be in a frame), to a different page that the datagrid is on.

How can I do this?
Here's the click code for the button:

```
Private Sub btnPlaceOrder_Click(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) Handles btnPlaceOrder.Click
    Dim _M As New Main
    _M.InnerFrame.Navigate(New ManualOrder())
    Me.Close()
End Sub
```

Comment: How is the main window in a frame?  Please name these windows and pages and frames.  "To a differenct page that the datagrid in on" is not clear.

Comment: The main window contains a frame in which the pages are navigated to.

I need to navigate to a page inside this from, from a popped up dialog window

Answer (score 0, accepted):

figured it out for myself.

I needed to find the frame from the main application window in order to do this:

```
_F = Application.Current.Windows.Item(0).FindName("InnerFrame")
```